# Docker Elastic Beanstalk deployment problems: CREATE works but DEPLOY fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using elastic beanstalk to deploy server that uses Docker. I am using the eb terminal package. When I create my app and run it locally both with just docker and with the `eb local` commands it works. Next when I deploy using

```
eb create -i t2.micro my-docker-env
```

It works and I can hit the api and everything. BUT when I edit the code and run

```
eb deploy my-docker-env
```

It fails with error `ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.` And within the logs it's saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'`. I want to emphasize that the code works when I create it (i.e. deploy it the first time) but only fails when I deploy an update to the code. Note that I don't make any changes to the Dockerfile or the requirements or anything. I tried this with literally just changing a print statement in the application code and still got this error.

Also extra info: I don't use `Dockerrun.aws.json` since I'm using my own Docker image. So I have my own `Dockerfile` within the repo that does pip install and runs python flask app.

Any help will be appreciated.