# Elastic Beanstalk deploy always fails but works if starting new environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Similar question found here with no answers: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59974339/docker-elastic-beanstalk-deployment-problems-create-works-but-deploy-fails)

I am having a tough time replicating this issue. But it has happened many times.

Basically, when I create the Elastic Beanstalk environment via Command Line like this:

1. `eb create`

   - set up the configuration
2. the environment is successfully deployed

**BUT**, (sometimes) if I change a simple print statement, and redeploy like this:

1. `eb deploy my-environment-name`
2. Deployment fails

I was unable to view the logs in this state, I basically then have to terminate the entire environment and then create the environment from scratch again.

Any idea what is causing this to happen? Like I said, it happens randomly so I was not able to get the logs, but one of the times, it mentioned that their was a problem with the docker file version, even though it works on creation.

This is my docker file:

```
# Build stage 
# 
FROM maven:3.8.1-jdk-8 
ADD src /tmp/src
ADD pom.xml /tmp/pom.xml
RUN mvn -f /tmp/pom.xml clean package

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:8
COPY --from=0 /tmp/target/para-host-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/para.jar
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/para.jar"]
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without the logs. It's worth mentioning that deploying doesn't always create new instances. So you might have some ebextension scripts that don't take that into account and expect a clean machine.